# How to launch different service instances from different activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, instances

In my Android application I would launch differents instance of my service from different activity.
For example from activity A I want launch the service and from activity B I want launch another instance of the same service.

From the differents activity I'm using these code lines:

Activity A

```
svc = new Intent(AActivity.this, Service.class);
svc.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startService(svc);
        `
```

Activity B

```
svc = new Intent(BActivity.this, Service.class);
svc.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startService(svc);
```

The problem is thath only one service is created.
There is a solution? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want different instances of the same service?
Why not just use one service instance and then bind to it from your different activities?

Answer (score 0):

> For example from activity A I want launch the service and from activity B I want launch another instance of the same service.

This is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into doing this as well, but after doing a bunch of digging, I came to the same conclusion.  It isn't possible to have multiple instances of the same service running.

This is a quote from the android dev forums:

> Services are singletons.  You do not use stopService() with bindService().
>   A service remains instantiated as long as there are one or more clients to it, OR it is
>   explicitly in the start > state.
>
> Dianne Hackborn,
>   Android framework engineer

Sorry for the bad news.

Cheers